# Unknown tag name with Wicket namespace

Tags: java, wicket

I use Wicket 6.7.0 and I get the following exception at runtime:

Last cause: Unknown tag name with Wicket namespace: 'panel'. Might be you haven't installed the appropriate resolver? '' (line 3, column 2)

I'm extending the BookmarkablePageLink and my component has it's own markup html. 
It is similar to the code from wicket-bootstrap: 
https://github.com/l0rdn1kk0n/wicket-bootstrap/blob/master/bootstrap-core/src/main/java/de/agilecoders/wicket/core/markup/html/bootstrap/button/BootstrapBookmarkablePageLink.java

ExtBookMarkablePageLink.java

```
public class ExtBookMarkablePageLink<T> extends BookmarkablePageLink<T> {

private final Component label;

public <C extends Page> ExtBookMarkablePageLink(String id, Class<C> pageClass) {
    this(id, pageClass, new PageParameters());
}

public <C extends Page> ExtBookMarkablePageLink(String id, Class<C> pageClass, final PageParameters parameters) {
    super(id, pageClass, parameters);
    add(label = newLabel("label"));
}

protected Component newLabel(final String markupId) {
    return new Label(markupId, new Model<String>("")).setRenderBodyOnly(true);
}

@Override
protected IMarkupSourcingStrategy newMarkupSourcingStrategy() {
    return new PanelMarkupSourcingStrategy(true);
}

public ExtBookMarkablePageLink<T> setLabel(IModel<?> label) {
    this.label.setDefaultModel(label);
    return this;
}

}
```

ExtBookMarkablePageLink.html

```
<!doctype html>
<html xmlns:wicket="http://wicket.apache.org">
<wicket:panel>
<span wicket:id="label"></span>
    </wicket:panel>
</html>
```

Comment: In `Panel` there's:  static
 {
    WicketTagIdentifier.registerWellKnownTagName(PANEL);
 } Could you try this as well in `ExtBookMarkablePageLink`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should register the panel tag in the static block of your component:

```
public class ExtBookMarkablePageLink<T> extends BookmarkablePageLink<T> {

    static {
        WicketTagIdentifier.registerWellKnownTagName(PANEL);
    }

    // ...
}
```